# yiistrap TbNav button styles

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

ive been searching how to change the button styles or atleast to leave it to default buttons.. the problem i have now (i dont know why its happening) is that buttons in the TbNav when selected are not looking like they should..

the menu looks like this ['page'](http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/widgets#navbar)

but when you pass the cursor over them, they look like if it still were working with the default menu that comes with yii, also when you click on them.. still looking like default.

```
<div id="mainmenu">
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavBar',array(
    'brandLabel'=>TbHtml::b(Yii::app()->name),
    'color'=>TbHtml::NAVBAR_COLOR_INVERSE,
    'items'=>array(
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                array('label'=>'About', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'about')),
                array('label'=>'Contact', 'url'=>array('/site/contact')),
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbNav',
            'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'pull-right'),
            'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
            ),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

i also would like to recieve a hint about how to change the button styles

Comment: Try to remove everything in the 'assets' folder.

Comment: no clue, still looking the same

Comment: Check whether everything mentioned in the [configuration part of the documentation](http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/started#configuration) has been implemented. Also remove any of the standard CSS files originally referenced by the generated application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed this problem by not including the main.css in the main layout.. i had to make one by my own inside the theme folder.. the problem was that main.css had a mainmenu color background and text color in thoses divs.. i did not include the mainmenu in my custom main.css on the theme so it wont cause more problem